# Add EvenLogging to an IHost container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, event-log, servicehost

I’m creating a console app and have recently started adding custom services to the `IHost` container so I can simply pass the `IHost` to any number of factory classes and have everything thing I need to configure them. But I’ve gotten stuck when it comes to adding Windows Event Logging as a service, could use some help getting past this.

My Main static method in Program calls `CreateHostBuilder` and returns an `IHostBuilder` as shown below.

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

        var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                logging.AddEventLog(eventViewerSettings =>
                {
                    eventViewerSettings.SourceName = "MeCore2";
                    eventViewerSettings.LogName = "Application";
                    eventViewerSettings.MachineName = ".";
                });
            })
           .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddDbContext<MeCore2Context>())
            // Add custom service for performing DNS queries
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTransient<IDnsQueryService>(DnsQueryFactory.Create))
            // Add custom service for Managing Runtime Environment Settings
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTransient<IEnvironmentSettings>(EnvironmentSettingsFactory.Create))
            // Add custom service for Managing String Extractions
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTransient<IExtractStringsService>(ExtraxtStringsFactory.Create))
            // Add custom service for IP GeoLocation
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTransient<IIpGeolocationService>(IpGeolocationFactory.Create));

        return hostBuilder;
    }
```

My factory classes are implemented like this.

```
public static class DnsQueryFactory
{
    public static DnsQueryService Create(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        bool exceptionDisplayOnly = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEnvironmentSettings>().WriteErrorsToEventLogs;
        IHost host = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHost>();

        return new DnsQueryService(exceptionDisplayOnly, host);
    }
}
```

And my concrete service constructors are implemented like this.

```
    public DnsQueryService(bool exceptionDisplayOnly, IHost host)
    {
        this.exceptionDisplayOnly = exceptionDisplayOnly;
        this.logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
        this.environmentSettings = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IEnvironmentSettings>();
    }
```

When I ran the app after setting up in this manner, I was unable to pull an `ILogger` from the host container, I could though, pull an `ILoggerFactory` then I needed to take some additional steps before I had a fully functional `ILogger`.

I would like to be able to pull the `ILogger` from the Host container with it fully configured and ready to use for exception handling, warnings, and basic information logging. But I'm stumped here as I can't seem to get the right syntax for using the `ILoggingBuilder` or `ILoggerFactory` into the Host container.

I started down the path of creating a static class `EventLoggingServices` that would accept an `IServiceProvider` finish out the configuration steps and return an `ILogger`, but this too has got me stumped. I'm close but not where I need to be and can't find a blog that covers this approach, either that or I'm going at this the wrong way, to begin with. Appreciate the help and thanks in advance.

I believe I've answered my own question with the following code, it is writing to the event logs. I implemented a factory method to encapsulate the `ILogger<T>` as follows.

```
public static class EventLoggingFactory
{
    public static ILogger<IEventLogging> Create(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new EventLogging().EventLogger;
    }
}

public class EventLogging : IEventLogging
{
    #region *-- Private Members --*

    private ILogger<IEventLogging> _logger = null;

    #endregion

    public ILogger<IEventLogging> EventLogger { get { return this._logger; } }

    public EventLogging()
    {
        EventLogSettings settings = new EventLogSettings();
        settings.LogName = "Application";
        settings.SourceName = "MeCore2";
        settings.MachineName = ".";
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
        loggerFactory.AddProvider(new EventLogLoggerProvider(settings));
        this._logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<IEventLogging>();
    }
}

public interface IEventLogging
{
    ILogger<IEventLogging> EventLogger { get; }
}
```

And in my HostBuilder the following:

```
.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTransient<ILogger>(EventLoggingFactory.Create))
```

What I haven't considered and I'm still wrapping my head around are service LifeTimes. Using this approach the `Ilogger` is Transient, but is that the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

The final code block on this post has been a sufficient solution for my needs. With a little more effort I've been able to expand the features used to capture log data for viewing in Windows Event Viewer.